# TransformerEncoderLayer has nondeterministic random output?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, transformer-model

```
import torch
from torch import nn
class MyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.encoder_layer = nn.TransformerEncoderLayer(d_model=1, nhead=1, dim_feedforward=2)
        self.trans = nn.TransformerEncoder(self.encoder_layer, num_layers=1)
    def forward(self, x):
        y = self.trans(x)
        return y
model = MyModel()
model.eval()
x = torch.tensor([[1.],[1.]])
model(x)
```

I have a model with just one encoder layer. I set the model to evaluation and each time I run inference I get a different output. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot that weight initialization was random and needed to be fixed by setting a seed.